# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- ['04 Nissan Sentra - Smoke from engine compartment after long drive](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7457/04-nissan-sentra-smoke-from-engine-compartment-after-long-drive)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Easiest way to disable the A/C compressor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/easiest-way-to-disable-the-a-c-compressor)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [2003 Honda Accord - driver side low beam light bulb replacement](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7564/2003-honda-accord-driver-side-low-beam-light-bulb-replacement)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Emergency brake light always on](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/emergency-brake-light-always-on)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Daytime running light failure -- one side only](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7526/daytime-running-light-failure-one-side-only)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do you recognize this connector?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/do-you-recognize-this-connector)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to fix a door scratch?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7370/how-to-fix-a-door-scratch)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What to check if fuel consumption is too high?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/what-to-check-if-fuel-consumption-is-too-high)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [2000 Dodge Ram 1500 won't idle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/2000-dodge-ram-1500-wont-idle)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Car shakes when in gear at red light](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7422/car-shakes-when-in-gear-at-red-light)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

Answer (score 2):

I recently joined this SE site and do enjoy it. With my experience in other sites in SE, it seems the moderators are a lot more lax in what posts are allowed. I see a lot of opinion being passed off as fact, while those who are wanting answers get a plethora of them ... many of them wrong or misleading. I would think there should be more required for links and references in posts when answering questions. If there isn't, it seems to me there is just a lot of "shootin' from the hip" going on.

I've been a mechanic for over 30 years. Some of the explanations I've seen in the past few days of being on here should make people cough, as it is not sound advice for helping people with their mechanical and maintenance needs. Who is making calls on these answers? I guess I could be putting flags on these answers for moderator review, but I'm wondering about the veracity of some of the moderators as well.

SE sites should be about questions with answers, to provide a database of answers others can benefit from ... at least that is my understanding. I would think this site should be a little more proactive about these things.

As an aside, as a moderator of several automotive forums, I have found at least one area you should stay away from: oil. There are more opinions (wrong and not) about oil and what type is better. Note I did not say "brand" ... that's a whole different story. If you allow questions about oil you will find a plethora of different opinions of which most are wrong or at the least misleading. If you try to find information on the web, there too you will find a bunch of different opinions. There is very little fact out there (not saying it doesn't exist) to find, but it is very hard to decipher what is fact and what is opinion. This is a very ugly and contentious area of the vehicle industry. Not saying they shouldn't be completely allowed, but should be closely looked at to ensure the rhetoric is kept to a minimum.

Comment: Hey Paul! A belated welcome - good to see more folks getting active here. Please don't hesitate to down-vote answers that are primarily unsubstantiated opinion, particularly if the advice that results is potentially harmful or misleading. Future readers will thank you! If an answer is of particularly poor quality, don't hesitate to flag - regardless of what the moderator team does as a result, it's useful feedback; better to say something than nothing. Also, might want to raise a separate meta discussion regarding oil; could be worth setting up some guidelines for such questions here.